# api new value each time

Tags: php, json, api

So i have my PHP where i GET from an API, I want to get som URL from the API to display images, but when i go into "entries -> plprogram$thumbmails" i then need to go into another value which is the size of the image. So it could look like "orig-1080x1920" or "orig-1500x1000" All the images have different values, how can i automatically find and set the value for the one that fits the image?
Here's the code:

```
foreach ($response["entries"] as $value){
    //Get title of the movie
    $description = $value["description"];
    //Get image of the cover
    $image = $value['plprogram$thumbnails'][0]['plprogram$thumbnails'];
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$image');</script>";
    //var_dump($title);
    echo ("
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='card text-center' style='width: 25rem;'>
      <img src='$image' class='card-img-top' alt='...'>
        <div class='card-body'>
          <h5 class='card-title'>$title</h5>
          <p class='card-text'>$description</p>
          <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    ");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is ment with "that fits the image"? What is "the image"? What dimensions got "the image"? What exactly means "fit" in this context?

Comment: Well, all the images have some predefined sizes, which could be like 1080x1920 px(pixels)
In the JSON data i first need the size which is predifned to get the url for the picture.
But the predefined size is not the same for each picture.

Comment: If the response that contains the image size is JSON-encoded, perhaps you could update your question to show a sample of it. What do you see if you `var_dump($value);` for each iteration of your loop? Does the image size appear in there, like the description does?

Comment: The dump of $value gives a big mess, it is all the data the api json contains, 
The thing is that i need to figure out how to get into the right "orig-SOMETHING"
I tried doing it like this:
$image = $value['plprogram$thumbnails'][0]['plprogram$thumbnails']

Comment: Well, I wouldn 't mess with image sizes. For what? Your markup shows, that you want to display images, that all should have the same size to fit into your layout. Why not setting a responsive size with css? This is more efficient than messing around with different image sizes.

Comment: ... and furthermore: Show us the relevant part of the JSON structure, that shows the different image sizes.

Comment: Here is a JSON viewer. Go to entires, "some entry" - plprogram$thumbnails

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=url.https%3A%2F%2Ffeed.entertainment.tv.theplatform.eu%2Ff%2FjGxigC%2Fbb-all-pas%3Fform%3Djson%26lang%3Dda%26byProgramType%3Dmovie&right=url.https%3A%2F%2Ffeed.entertainment.tv.theplatform.eu%2Ff%2FjGxigC%2Fbb-all-pas%3Fform%3Djson%26lang%3Dda%26byProgramType%3Dmovie